# What happened to Microsoft.FSharp.Math.Matrix?

Tags: f#, matrix

Kind of strange how this class type has dropped of the F# released with VS2010

Does anyone know where it has gone?  or where it is now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is in the F# powerpack, which is used by the F# team for "unstable" code that will get released and updated more often than the main release of F# and libraries. (Note that the code is still high-quality code, you should ignore most of the connotations that "unstable" has in this case). It's just a way for the F# team to get more experimental code out there quickly, once F# is released for real.

The powerpack is on [codeplex](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Apparently the download link is broken now (MS... <sigh>). It appears to be supported on Codeplex, here: http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/